# Hide menu in option menu when login/logout

Tags: android, eclipse, menu, sharedpreferences, optionmenu

i have an app with login logout session with pref menu.
i want to when user is login, option menu only show log out menu. But when user is log out, option menu is only show login menu. i have try some example but in my case always give me error in major.

this is my main.xml

```
    <item
            android:id="@+id/Login"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/Login">
  </item>

 <item 
           android:id="@+id/Logout" 
           android:title="Logout" />
```

this is my config.Java

```
public class Config {
//URL to our login.php file
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.kinandayu.com/login.php";

//Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

//If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

//Keys for Sharedpreferences
//This would be the name of our shared preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
}
```

this is my option menu in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.Login:
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            return true;
        case R.id.Logout:
            logout();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Can anybody help me in my case, every answer is helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create to layouts for your menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(LOGGED_IN){
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logout, menu);
    }else{
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just check the state of the log-in session before inflating the menu

Comment: my option menu is gone when i using this

Comment: Can you show the code as to how you implemented this

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         boolean loggedin = prefs.getBoolean("loggedin", false); 
         
   prefs.edit().putBoolean("loggedin", loggedin).commit();
   
   if(loggedin){ 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    
      }else{
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      }
      return true;
  }

Comment: it's still show 2 menus login and logout @Hespen, do i do a mistake?

Comment: You are editing the loggedin value in the menu? You should remove the line prefs.edit().putBoolean("loggedin", loggedin).commit(). That line should be placed after the login attempt was successful. Also it would be impossible to show two menu's if there's an if-statement. That would mean your function is called twice, which is only possible if you are using something like fragments.

Comment: my fool. In my case, would you give me a code to check login state? i 've tried until now but i still get this issue @Hespen

Comment: i've get what i want. this is my final code public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   if(loggedIn){ 
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.Logout);
    item.setVisible(true); 
      }
   else {
      }
      return true;
  }   i set default logout menu as invisible, and this is work when login or logout. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        if(loggedIn){
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.Logout);
            item.setVisible(true);
            MenuItem items = menu.findItem(R.id.Login);
            items.setVisible(false);

        }
        else {
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.Login);
            item.setVisible(true);
            MenuItem items = menu.findItem(R.id.Logout);
            items.setVisible(false);

        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.Login:
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            return false;
        case R.id.Logout:
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
            logout();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```